# Python: Reading Excel 2007 files under Linux environment

Tags: python, excel, excel-2007, openpyxl

I want to read excel 2007 files via python on my **Ubuntu** server. I have already checked http://www.python-excel.org/ xlwt and xlrd but it seems like none of them can read excel 2007 files.

What would be your recommendation?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Try [pyXLSX](http://github.com/leegao/pyXLSX). There is also [openpyxl](http://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/) which can also read / write .xlsx files.